Por qué al agregar un libro me crea un nuevo autor en mi base de datos?
Estoy tomando un curso de webAPI con ASP.NET Core, y no sé por qué, pero me crea un nuevo autor al momento de hacer la petición POST al libro.
El modelo de Autor:
public class Autor {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<Libro> Libros { get; set; } = new List<Libro>();
}

El modelo de Libro:
public class Libro {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     public int IdAutor { get; set; }    
     public Autor Autor { get; set; } = new Autor();
 }

Mi ApplicationDbContext
public class ApplicationDbContext:DbContext{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options) {}
    public DbSet<Autor> Autores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Libro> Libro { get; set; }
}

Mi método POST en LibrosController
public async Task < ActionResult > Post(Libro libro) {
    bool existeAutor = await _context.Autores.AnyAsync(autor => autor.Id == libro.IdAutor);
    if(!existeAutor)
    {
        return BadRequest("El autor no existe para ese libro");
    }
    _context.Add(libro);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok("Libro agregado correctamente");
}

Manualmente agrego el title y el idAutor en el POST de Libro, lo demás lo borro

Luego de hacer POST en Libro, me crea uno nuevo vacío en Autores

También al hacer GET en Libros, me sale el idAutor que se creó "automáticamente" en Autores

Espero esto haya sido lo más entendible posible, en verdad que estoy barado desde ayer:(
Muchas gracias:)

No soy experto en ORM (Object Relational Mapping) con asp.net pero en tu entidad Libro estás haciendo asignando el campo Autor como new Autor, es decir, siempre que creas un Libro también creas un nuevo Autor. No veo que establezcas la relación entre los campos IdAutor y Autor. Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo de cómo establecer una relación entre dos entidades. Quizás deberías buscar otros ejemplos de ORM con asp.net. para poder adaptar lo que ya tienes hecho.
